# How to show posts in grid style on search result page?

Tags: posts, search

I want to show posts in a grid-style layout on the search result page when someone searches for something using the search bar. Right now it is showing a list-style layout. I also want to hide the "excerpt" and "continue reading" link. Website link - http://test123.42web.io/ . When clicking on the website link, please wait a little for the website to load up, it is a bit slow.

Comment: Assuming you are familiar with coding, you can override the search result page by adding a `search.php` file in you theme root folder.

Comment: I am not familiar with codes and stuff.